# C++: Inherit class with templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I know how to inherit classes with templates in general.  But when it comes to nested classes/templates, I have no clue and can't find anything on the Internet (perhaps because I don't know the keywords for it).

```
template <typename T>
class A;

template <class T1, class T2>
class B;

template < typename T1, class T2, class T3 >
class C2:
    public C< A<T1>, B<T2, T3> >
{};
```

I want `C2` to be defined the same way `C` is defined, i.e. `C2< A<T1>, B<T2, T3> >` and not `C2<T1, T2, T3>`. But I  don't know any syntax or workaround how to achieve that.

Edit: T.C. is right, I want the end user to write only `C2< A<T1>, B<T2, T3> > foo;`, `C2<foo, bar> foo;` should not be allowed.

Comment: I have read your question a few times, and I don't really get what you are asking. First of all: how is `C` defined?

Comment: You mean you want the end user to write `C2< A<T1>, B<T2, T3> >  foo;` rather than `C2<T1, T2, T3> foo;`? What should happen if they write `C2<Bar, Baz> foo;`?

Comment: `template<class, class> class C2; /* undefined */ template<class T1, class T2, class T3> class C2<A<T1>, B<T2, T3> > : public C< A<T1>, B<T2, T3> > { /* definition */ };`

Comment: You may be able to hack this together with static assertions and type traits (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/), although I am really not sure. I also do not see the point of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
template <typename T>
class A {};

template <class T1, class T2>
class B {};

template < typename T1, class T2>
class C {};

// forward declare C2 but don't define it.    
template < typename T1, class T2 > class C2;

// Create the only specialization that depends on using A and B.
template < typename T1, class T2, class T3 >
class C2<A<T1>, B<T2, T3> >: public C< A<T1>, B<T2, T3> >
{};

int main()
{
   C2<A<int>, B<double, float>> c1; // OK.
                                    // This creates an instance of the
                                    // only specialization that has
                                    // been defined.

   C2<int, double> c2;              // Not OK.
                                    // The generic template class has
                                    // been forward declared but has not
                                    // not been defined.
}
```

Comment: It is indeed as you say, but please explain why this works. For the first sight it didn't even seem valid for me ...

Comment: @GáborAngyal, see the updated answer.Hope the additional comments makes it clearer.

Comment: Oh. So its a template specializing a template. Very clever!

Comment: @GáborAngyal It's called partial specialization.